# Is there a polynomial time algorithm to test whether a number exponent of some number?

Tags: algorithm, analysis, computation-theory

Just study the famous paper `PRIMES is in P` and get confused.

First step of the proposed algorithm is `If (n=a^b for nature number a and b>1), output COMPOSITE.` Since the whole algorithm runs in polynomial time, this step must also complete in O((log n)^c)(given input size is O(log n). However, I can't figure out any algorithm to hit the target after some googling.

QUESTION:

Is there any algorithm available to test whether a number exponent of some other number in polynomial time?

Thanks and Best Regards!

Comment: This would probably a better fit for http://cstheory.stackexchange.com

Comment: Is `a` known? If so, just repeatedly divide `n` by `a` and see if you eventually get 1; if we have constant-time division, this takes `log_a(n)` steps. Alternatively, just compute `log_a(n)` directly (presumably by `log(n) / log(a)`) and see if it's an integer. :)

Comment: @Dougal Thanks for the response. I think `a` is unknown or I miss something. IIRC, the main idea of the algorithm is establishing some rules to claim the number a composite. If the claim fails under these rules, then the number must be a exponent of a prime. This first step eliminate the case where exponent greater than 1.

Comment: b <= log2(n)  can you check whether a = b^n for a given b in constant time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `n=a^b` (for a > 1) then b ≤ log<sub>2</sub> n, we can check for all `b`'s smaller than `log n` to test this, we can iterate for finding `b` from 2 to log n, and for finding `a` we should do binary search between 1..sqrt(n). But binary search takes O(`logn`) time for iteration, finally in each step of search(for any found `a` for checking) we should check that whether a<sup>b</sup> == n and this  takes O(log n), so total search time will be O(log<sup>3</sup>n). may be there is a faster way but by knowing that [AKS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test) is O(log<sup>6</sup>n) this O(log<sup>3</sup>n) doesn't harm anything.

Answer (score 2):

A number n is a perfect power if there exists b and e for which b^e = n. For instance 216 = 6^3 = 2^3 * 3^3 is a perfect power, but 72 = 2^3 * 3^2 is not. The trick to determining if a number is a perfect power is to know that, if the number is a perfect power, then the exponent e must be less than log2 n, because if e is greater then 2^e will be greater than n. Further, it is only necessary to test prime e, because if a number is a perfect power to a composite exponent it will also be a perfect power to the prime factors of the composite component; for instance, 2^15 = 32768 = 32^3 = 8^5 is a perfect cube root and also a perfect fifth root. Thus, the algorithm is to make a list of primes less than log2 n and test each one. Since log2 n is small, and the list of primes is even smaller, this isn't much work, even for large n.

You can see an implementation [here](http://programmingpraxis.com/2012/03/13/perfect-power-predicate/).

Comment: it's not just a question of whether it's "small" or not, it's a question of whether you can do everything in O(log(n)).

Comment: The outer loop is over the primes less than log2 n. Since there are x / log x primes less than x, the inner loop will be executed log n / log log n times. Now log log n is very small, a constant for all practical purposes, so we'll say the outer loop is log n. Each time the inner loop is executed it uses Newton's method to compute a root, which converges quadratically.

Comment: you're full comment appears to be missing, but that sounds like O(log(n)^2) (and i think it would be better to just update the answer than comment here).

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally pressed the enter key in the middle of writing the comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean isPerfectPower(int a) {
    if(a == 1) return true;
    for(int i = 2; i <= (int)Math.sqrt(a); i++){
        double pow = Math.log10(a)/Math.log10(i);
        if(pow == Math.floor(pow) && pow > 1) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```